# Is there a dedicated tool to display the pixel value visually in the pixel itself?

Tags: opencv, colors, computer-vision, rgb, pixel

In OpenCV 3x there was such an opportunity. When you greatly increase the scale in pixels, their values ​​were displayed. For example 100,100,100. But in version 4x this feature has ceased to exist. At least through the usual imshow.

Comment: You mean the visual debugger? https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dcf/tutorial_cvv_introduction.html

Comment: no, he means the **Qt backend** for the `highgui` module of OpenCV, which allows interactive zooming and it shows the RGB numbers in each pixel, if zoomed in enough. the Qt backend is still there, but the binary package downloads don't build it anymore, because Qt is a huge dependency. if you want it, you can build OpenCV yourself with Qt, and then it'll do that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz да, я имею это в виду. Спасибо за ответ!